# TapGestureRecognizer in the view made button from the view disable

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I've got a uivew as a rootView. There is a button and a textfield in the view.

When textfield is in editting mode, the keyboard appears.

To dismiss keyboard, I add a uiTapGestureRecognizer to the whole view. So that When touch on the screen, keyboard will disappear.

But the button in the view will also get this gesture recognizer. When keyboard is showing, touch in the button can make it highlighted, but can not trigger the action of this button.

Is there any way to make the button action working when keyboard is showing in the view? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why would you want to activate a button that is hiding beneath something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UIGestureRecognizerDelegate** in .h file

in .m

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

       if (touch.view == yourbutton )
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! May I ask another related one. How can I add a gesture recognizer to a whole window in a case I use a navigationcontroller. If I use 'self.view addgesture...', the navigationbar is out of control.

Comment: I've got the answer! just use these code: self.navigationContrller.view addGestureRecognizer:..  The whole view is the root view of navigationcontroller.